# How to access hidden GRUB in Xubuntu

Tags: 12.04, grub2, xubuntu

I have recently installed Xubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP. My parents don't use Xubuntu, so I configured the GRUB file as written in some articles. I changed:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT= 4 #Assuming Windows is the fifth menu entry
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Now whenever I press and hold the Shift key it says `GRUB loading`, but does not show GRUB and boots directly into XP. How can I access grub.cfg to change the settings so I'll have correct settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to boot from the xubuntu CD in live CD mode - then you can mount the `/` or `/boot` file system and make the changes you need to make.

Alternately you can boot the system rescue CD (http://www.sysresccd.org/) and do the same.

The tricky part of this is working out which disk partition has `/boot` on it.

Once you have started xubuntu in Live CD mode open a terminal and use `sudo` to get a root shell. Alternately, boot the system rescue CD and it will drop you in a root shell.

Then look in `/dev` for files like `sda1` `sda2` `sdb1` etc.

Try mounting each in turn:

```
# mount /dev/sd1 /mnt
# ls /mnt
# umount /mnt
```

If `mount` gives an error, ignore that partition. If `ls /mnt` shows a directory called `boot`, then look in there for the files you have to change to reconfigure grub.

Comment: can you be more specific as I don't know much about it

Comment: more detail added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LiveCD to boot from, and edit grub.cfg that way.  Mount the partition where /boot is, and edit /boot/grub/menu.lst. Change the timeout.  Also try pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and see if that helps.

Another way is to use Grub Customizer, also from the LiveCD.  For information on how to install Grub Customizer, once the LiveCD is up and running, see [HOWTO: Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Other options you can use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), and [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)